# My comment box not storing anything in database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a comment box in PHP to store its values in a database.

```
 <?php
    include('connect.php');
    $name= isset($_POST['name']);
    $comment= isset($_POST['comment']);
    $submit=isset($_POST['submit']);
    if($submit)
    {
    if($name && $comment)
    {
    $insert= "INSERT INTO comment(name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')";

    }
    else
    {
    echo "please fill out the field";
    }


    }
    ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Comment box</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="comment-box.php">
    <table>
    <tr><td>NAME:</td> <td><input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan="2">comment:</td></tr> 
    <tr><td colspan="2"> <textarea name="comment"></textarea> </td></tr> 
    <tr><td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="comment"></textarea> </td></tr> 

    </table>


    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My connection file connect.php does not store anything in my database.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance :) lol I hate this redbox error :D

```
    <?php

    mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("comment") or die ("connect select DB");  

    ?>
```

Comment: Where do you execute the `sql` statement? I can only see where you define it. Also you should not use  deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: You're at risk of SQL injection, you need to `prepare` your statements before they're sent.

Comment: Also, the values you're trying to insert are `boolean` - the return type of `isset`.

Answer (score 3):

At least you have query which you do not execute:

```
$insert= "INSERT INTO comment(name,comment) VALUES ('$name','$comment')";
```

You have to run [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), but as it is deprecated you should consider
switching to [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) or [PDO::query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php).

```
$res = mysqli_query($con, $insert, ...)
```

where `$con` is your connection.